# Is frame number actually base address of memory where pages stored in paging?

Tags: operating-system

My question is related to the paging system of memory management.
I'm a little bit confused about the frame number.
Is frame number actually base address of memory where a page stored?
If it is base address then why OS does multiplication frame number × page size (page no. × frame size + offset) to find the physical address.
Can't it just add offset with frame number to find a physical address?

Answer (score 1):

Physical memory is divided into PAGE FRAME.

A process logical address space is divided into PAGES.

The page table maps PAGES to PAGE FRAMES.

> Is frame number actually base address of memory where a page stored?

NO.

> If it is base address then why OS does multiplication frame number × page size (page no. × frame size + offset) to find the physical address. Can't it just add offset with frame number to find physical address.

It's not.